# wpa_supplicant : Blacklist wireless networks by BSSID

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, wpa-supplicant

I am currently using wpa_supplicant to connect to my wireless network. The wireless network is extended with at least 30 different access points having the same SSID, and it takes a lot of time to connect because 10 of them aren't working properly (timing out, taking a couple of minutes to acknowledge,...).

I would like to know if there is a way to blacklist the non-working access points from their BSSID so I can ignore them and connect faster to the wireless network by probing working access points only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use "wpa_cli blacklist xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx" just after wpa_supplicant starts.  I don't know how sticky it is.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use network option bssid_blacklist, take a look for it in the example file: https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: This answer does the trick without having to hack around.

Comment: I guess you meant "bssid_ignore"

Answer (score 1):

Wire up [this code](http://hostap.epitest.fi/gitweb/gitweb.cgi?p=hostap-1.git;a=blob;f=wpa_supplicant/blacklist.c;h=8f12ac995a3c9d904a5bfea608d7c7e65d12636c;hb=HEAD) to a command-line option.

I don't think there is any built-in setting to take care of this but basically you should be able to go to [main.c](http://hostap.epitest.fi/gitweb/gitweb.cgi?p=hostap-1.git;a=blob;f=wpa_supplicant/main.c;h=e196f3c4a42833f903ae4e388fed21e0dd072014;hb=HEAD), and wire up a command line option like `--blacklist=00:11:22:33:44;55:66:77:88:99` (the BSSIDs separated by semicolons).

To make it persistent you'd have to store it in `wpa_supplicant.conf` but it's easy enough to replace `wpa_supplicant` with a wrapper that adds your --blacklist parameter.

If you manage to cook up a patch and it seems relatively bug-free and generally useful, you may want to submit it upstream.

NOTE: Intermediate knowledge of the C programming language is required to complete this task. If you don't have the knowledge, you may get better results by asking at another site like StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll try to fork it and see what I can do with it tonight by making a blacklist command and blacklisting AP in the config file. I'll post the details here once it's done.